# Installation of Jellybean or Kitkat on Micromax A89?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, 4.3-jelly-bean, stock-android

I have Micromax A89 mobile with ICS 4.0.4 OS AND MTK 6577 processor. I would like to install Jellybean 4.2.2 OS on my MMX A89 device. Is it possible? Even I would like to install Kitkat 4.4 too if possible?

1. What are the steps to install Jellybean 4.2.2 (or 4.3) on my MMX A89 device (safer way to install)?
2. If I could able to install Jellybean 4.2.2 on MMX A89 then further it is possible to install Kitkat 4.4 in future?

Can anybody help me for this?

Answer (score 1):

After searching in XDA, I found a few ROMs which are ICS-based but Jellybean or KitKat themed, I think there are not enough devs to port Jellybean or KitKat ROM for A89. You can try various ROMs to taste the look-and-feel of Jellybean or KitKat.

Here is the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/a89-ninja/development) of various ROM available in XDA.

Comment: So you mean to say that only Jellybean theme will be changes in MMX A89 and not actual OS?

Comment: Yes the roms are based on ICS

Comment: Then what about [Quantum Radicle V0.9 for Micromax A89 Ninja and Xolo A700](http://andro-build.org/2013/10/quantum-radicle-v0-9-for-micromax-a89-ninja-and-xolo-a700/) ?

Comment: `Quantum Radicle V0.9 is based on Android Icecream Sandwich 4.0.4 and not on Android Jellybean.` its there in the link you just gave

Comment: Yes. You're right. So that means we never ever get the feature of actual Jellybean or not Jellybean OS at all in MMX A89 but only theme?

Comment: Yes i think so, because need jellybean kernel and there is no popular devs for a89, as the phone is popular in India only

Answer (score 0):

MediaTek, unlike other brands, does not release Android updates in sync with (or soon after) an official Android release.

Moreover, they do not release the full source code for their chipsets, preventing Android developers from properly compiling ROMs.

They (MediaTek) have, however, announced that a 4.4.2 update will be rolling out 'soon', so you have no other options but to wait or flash an ICS-based, JB/KK-themed ROM.